# java swing jtextfiled unicode sinhala

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts, jtextfield

***************************UPDATED***********************************************************************
i have found a similar question :

here : [same question by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219612/how-to-make-jtextfield-render-supplementary-characters)

this one is with little details , but i still cant get it to work !

any help would be  glad fully accepted !

---

I want to type Sinhalese words in (J2SE)swing textfileds , but they don't appear correctly in Java , same text in notepad shows correct word. how can i fix this ?

notepad picture:
http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010080011O13734602521426968

java picture :
http://imageupper.com/i/?A0300010070011I13734604591427932

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: I think that you see the same letters, may be you just have to change `font`property with `textfield.setFont(..)`

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson , :) thanks !

@ nachokk , didn't  work :(

Comment: mm don't know then, i still think is the font

Comment: @nachokk , i have found this links :

[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/08/17/10050816.aspx)

[link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/)


you're right , its about the font.

Comment: @nachokk , then can't fix it no ?

Answer (score 1):

The same letters are in both images, so it's not problem of encoding.

The problem is that you have to set a proper `font` to the textfield. You can create the font if you don't have it, check this [setting custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717481/setting-custom-font-java)
@AndrewThompson answer :)

Comment: @stark9000 did you create the font and set to the textfield??

Comment: mmm don't know then xD , i don't think L&F is

Comment: @stark9000 did you try changing font style?

Comment: @ nachokk,

yes , didn't work.  

I think its about "glyphs".

Comment: picture : [link](http://imgbox.com/adidPCAx)

Character "ශ්‍ර" is made of -> ශ් +‍ ර 

When Type ශ + ්‍ර it Become  ශ්‍ර , Working Fine in 

Notepad and not Working in Java

Comment: In Java Instead it Become Like "ශ්‍ ර".

Answer (score 1):

Edit: That other user with the same question that you have mentioned is me. :)

As I found out, the char data type is not enough to render letters like "ශ්‍ර" because it needs 3 8bit characters. And the Java language isn't going to change the size of char data type just because we Sri Lankans want to render our characters. I had the similar question previously and I am the user you mentioned in your question.

"ශ්‍ ර" is shown with 2 8bit characters for each character and that's all we got till now. You might want to checout SWT because it shows characters pretty damn well in my experience.