# How to make JTextField render supplementary characters

Tags: java, swing, unicode

I tried to set some JTextComponent widgets (mostly JTextField components) to enter text in Unicode. In this, I need to render Sinhala characters. I set Iskoola Pota font in all my
This works fine most of the time but fails at some points.

characters with one or two characters render correctly.

```
Ex: අම්මා, වයඹ, අධිකාරිය
```

But the problem comes with characters with 3 characters.

```
Ex: ප්‍රවෘත්ති (THIS IS RENDERED AS ප්රවෘත්ති)
ව්‍යාපෘතිය (THIS IS RENDERED AS ව්යාපෘතිය)
```

The matter is characters such as `ප්‍ර is rendered as (ප්ර)` and `ව්‍යා is rendered as (ව්යා)`.
Screenshot is provided below.

Image is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQrQB.png
Here, අම්මා, වයඹ, අධිකාරිය is rendered properly but ප්‍රවෘත්ති and ව්‍යාපෘතිය words render incorrectly.

I have updated my JDK version and JRE also. Here is the version details as shown in NetBeans IDE.

```
Java: 1.7.0_40; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.0-b56
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_40-b43
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

I cannot understand how to implement the supplementary characters and surrogate pair API `jsr204` in my program. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: None of you characters uses surrogates, and have nothing to do with supplementary characters. The Unicode Sinhala range is U+0D80 – U+0DFF. Apparently the problem is a missing U+200D (ZERO WIDTH JOINER).

Comment: Dear sir, can you guide me how to do that programmatically? If I manually injected the ZERO WIDTH JOINER, will it be correctly rendered in the JTextField? OR should I implement a custom Document or a Text Renderer for the particular JTextField? Please help me in this issue, I really very much appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Machan mekata mokda kare?

Answer (score 4):

Try to see how layoutGlyphVector works with the triple chars. Does it provide correct representation? If yes you can try to  set custom GlyphPainter as described here http://java-sl.com/Scale_In_JEditorPane_GlyphPainter.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip you provided, `Try to see how layoutGlyphVector works with the triple chars` as you stated, but how can I check that with java? Please support me as it will be a huge help. Thanks again.

Comment: java.awt.Font has public GlyphVector layoutGlyphVector(FontRenderContext frc,
                                         char[] text,
                                         int start,
                                         int limit,
                                         int flags) you can get the vector and draw it to see how it is rendered