# Java: Font does not load (from external file)

Tags: java, fonts, awt

In a folder called *data*, I have a font file called *font.ttf*.

I want to read it in, like this:

```
try {
   Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
      new File("data/font.ttf")).deriveFont(12.0);
} catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {}
```

That worked fine up until I removed the same font from the **system** (it's still in the data folder!).
Now, it's just showing Java's generic font.

Is it even possible to read in a font from a file which is not in the System Fonts folder?

Comment: That code will not compile.  Please edit your question to show your actual code, including the `catch` block(s) which handle IOException and FontFormatException.

Comment: OK, added the catch block.

Comment: And is an exception actually occurring?  I suggest you replace that println with `throw new RuntimeException(e);`.  Unless you really want your application to run without having loaded your font.

Comment: It's not throwing any exception.
That's strange as the font file is actually there. And that "referring to a file" thing works if the font is actually installed on the system.

Comment: Solved by using a GraphicsEnvironment (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717481/setting-custom-font)

Comment: What you really mean is, you had to register the font after loading it.  Correct?

Comment: Exactly, it had to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be doing anything with that `Font f` once you've loaded it in, so you might simply be losing it due to block scoping.

```
Font fallback = load some system default;
Font myfont = null;

...

try {
  File ffile = new File("data/font.ttf");
  myfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, ffile).deriveFont(12);
} catch (FontFormatException ffe) {
  System.out.println("Tried to load a bad font...");
  ffe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("I have no idea what went wrong");
  ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  loadMyApplication(myfont == null ? fallback : myfont);
}
```

Or if you absolutely need that font for correct UI building or content rendering, call `loadMyApplication` in the `try` block, so that any catches prevent your application from loading.