# Swing JLabel display unicode " \u21B5 " as text not working

Tags: java, swing, unicode, virtual-keyboard

I am working with virtual keyboard in my application. I tried to display the arrow keys in the keyboard by unicodes, Some unicodes are displaying correctly others displaying as junk.

Ex:

```
\u2191 - Displaying
\u21B5 - Not displaying
```

Comment: Does your font have ↵? More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46699135/261156).

Comment: The font that I am using is not supporting that character. Thanks @CatalinaIsland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your OS includes a font that supports unicode.

Try one of the fonts from this list: http://unicode.org/resources/fonts.html

- [Alan Wood's Unicode fonts resource](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts.html)
- [Code2000, Code2001, and Code2002](http://www.fonts2u.com/font-designers/james-kass.html) (James Kass)
  A shareware Unicode font
- [Edward Trager's index of free/libre fonts](http://www.unifont.org/fontguide/)
- [Fonts By Range](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fontsbyrange.html) (Alan Wood)
  Information on the Unicode fonts available for each Unicode range
- [Gallery of Unicode Fonts](http://www.wazu.jp/)
  Hundreds of free Unicode fonts, with sample images from each
- [Google Noto fonts](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts)
      Intended as a source for fonts covering all scripts of The Unicode Standard, 
      released under Apache 2.0 license. Subdirectories for hinted and unhinted 
      versions, in bundles or individually.
- [Google Noto "early 
      access" fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess)
  This repository contains Noto fonts that are currently 
      under development, so they may not be stable, but are available for use and 
      comment. (A discussion forum is available.)
- [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)
  This font includes glyphs for every printable code point in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), and is regularly updated.
- [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) (Peter S. Baker)
  A Unicode-based font for medievalists.
- [Last Resort Font](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html)
  Link to downloading the Last Resort Font as well as its End User License Agreement
- Microsoft [Arial Unicode MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287247/description-of-the-arial-unicode-ms-font-in-word-2002) and 
        [Lucida Sans Unicode](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=160)
- [Monotype fonts](http://www.monotype.com/)
- [SIL Fonts](http://scripts.sil.org/FontDownloads)
- George Douros' Fonts for [Symbols and Ancient Scripts](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).
      
  *Symbola* covers many of the Symbol blocks, including Unicode 8.0 characters and pictographs (emoji).
      Older versions of Symbola are also available at [other download sites](http://www.fonts2u.com/symbola.font).
- [UniMath](http://www.appliedsymbols.com)
  An OpenType font which contains all of the TeX, LaTeX, and AMS TeX symbols, as well as hundreds of other symbols from the Unicode ranges that cover mathematical operators, 
  arrows, and technical symbols.

Comment: I can able to display the unicode by html. **JButton label = new JButton("<html>\u21B5</html>");**  But it causes performance issue since I am having many buttons in keyboard. Will HTML rendering takes time!!