# How to check which fonts I have available in java.awt?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, graphics, awt

In `java.awt` package, we have the [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) class. I want to see a list of all available fonts I have.

According to the documentation, this is possible through the `GraphicsEnvironment#getAllFonts()` method, but it is an abstract class. Why would I have to extend it, if it's supposed to tell me what fonts I have? The documentation for [`GraphicsEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) has no non-abstract subclasses, so I am confused on how I can view my options.

Comment: If an abstract class has concrete `static` methods, nothing stops you from using them directly.

Comment: Correction: GraphicsEnvironment has no *public* non-abstract subclasses.  AWT implementations are free to return a concrete implementation of GraphicsEnvironment whose class is not covered in the API documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a concrete instance of a [`GraphicsEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html), call the static method [`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getLocalGraphicsEnvironment())

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

Examples of use can be seen in answers to:

- [Getting fonts, sizes, bold,...etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/418556)
- [Display an Unicode character on JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335976/418556)
- [How to determine if 2 fonts have equivalent glyphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683631/418556)
- [Unicode characters in app doesn't show correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29028982/418556)
- [Unicode Character uncompatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471956/418556)
- ..