# Display not filled 2D array into JTextarea in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jtextarea

I want to display array elements in the "jTextArea1".My 2D array is not a completely filled one.it is like this. row_count = 4 and column_count =5.

#### 2D array:

```
    4 8 8 4 5
    2 7 5 6 
    6 4 1 8
    9 5 5 2
```

---

```
for(int r=0;r<row_count;r++)
{
    for(int c=0;c<column_count;c++)
    {
        jTextArea1.setText(Integer.toString(newArray[r][c]));

    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
}
```

Out put of the above code was just zero. what is the error of this code? thanks.

#### #

```
 0
```

Comment: `System.out.println("\n\n");` is the only line which will execute.

Comment: What is r and c? Or what are column and rowcount'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evenly space out 2d array in JTextArea without \t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444279/how-can-i-evenly-space-out-2d-array-in-jtextarea-without-t)

Answer (score 2):

you overwrite every time the text by doing:

```
jTextArea1.setText(Integer.toString(newArray[r][c]));
```

consider using the helpfull Arrays method **deepToString** and you will get rid off the nested loops :)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

so you can use:

```
jTextArea1.setText(Arrays.deepToString(newArray).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

Comment: Ok, How should I use above code in order to display 2D array elements into the jTextArea. Sorry i didn't understand the code you mentioned above.

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to java netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the TextArea input with `setText()`. Try `TextArea1.append()`.