# Java 8 get Path to Font

Tags: java, fonts, path

Is there a way to get the Path for a Font, regardless of the operating system?

e.g

```java
String path = getPathToFont("Arial");
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

Since Java 1.3, the `createFont()` method allows Java code to start drawing with a TrueType or PostScript font brought in from a file, or any other source of an `InputStream`, such as a JAR resource, network socket, or decrypted byte array. There's also a method that does take a `File`, but there's no method that returns the `File` even for fonts created that way.

Furthermore, the system-provided fonts (from `GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()`) are not required to only be TrueType or PostScript fonts. They could be in some OS-specific format, or some implementation-private format; and they might not be loaded from a file at all, instead backed by static data (in a class or native code), or drawn purely algorithmically.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Commons IO FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

`File fontFile = FileUtils.getFile("Arial.ttf") ;`

This will probably execute from your classpath, though.

Are you wanting to get the "system" fonts or the path to the system fonts?   For the former do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17514968/1739366):

`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()`

Comment: I need the absolute path to a font. e.g "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.ttf"

Comment: Do you mean the system fonts?   If you know what your fonts directory is and you're loading the Fonts from there, you can use FileUtils.    Are you trying to say (1) for a given Font object, can I can get the absolute file file? (2) can I find out where the system fonts directory is?   I think its the former, but its unclear.   If you could expand on your use-case that might help.

Comment: @NathanDunn second link is 404.