# Change JTextArea font type to sinhala

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea

I created text editor using JTextArea. But it doesn't work for sinhala font type.

```
t = new JTextArea();
t.setFont(new Font("kaputadotcom2004", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `kaputadotcom2004` isn´t a default font, you need to register your font to use it in your environment. You could do something like this (example taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java)):

```
try 
{
     GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
     ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("A.ttf")));
} 
catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) 
{
     //Handle exception
}
```

Comment: kAliert Thank you