# Add custom font file on java for executable JAR file

Tags: java, file, executable-jar, truetype

I am trying to add custom font to my jswing application, and i can't find how to properly upload the .ttf file so that i can use it once i create a executable jar file.

problem here, new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"cs_regular.ttf"))

thank you!

```
try {
         GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
             GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
         ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"cs_regular.ttf"))));
    } catch (FontFormatException|IOException e) {
         pr("Error_107");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite easy to create `java.io.File` from stream, you can create Font from stream directly.
look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862139/10999348

Answer (score 1):

This is my working code now

```
InputStream stream =ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cs_regular.ttf");
    try {
        csfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream).deriveFont(48f);
    } catch (FontFormatException|IOException e) {
        //handle exeption
    } 
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(csfont);
```