# Write Indian regional languages like Gujrati, Punjabit etc. in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I am able to write Hindi, Urdu in `JTextPane`, but not able to write other Indian regional languages in text pane. I have also downloaded the font for these languages, but it doesn't work.

How to write Indian ***regional*** languages like Gujrati, Punjabit etc in `JTextPane`?

**UPDATE :**

A piece of code as requested :

```
public class NewClass { 

    public static void main(String args[]) { 

        JFrame j = new JFrame("Hello!"); 
        j.setSize(200, 200); 
        JTextPane k = new JTextPane(); 
        k.setFont(new Font("Shree-Guj-0768W", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        j.add(k); j.setVisible(true); 

    }

}
```

I have set the gujrati(a Language) font in jtextpane, the existing content appear in gujrati,but when i write in the jtextpane boxes appears. Can we have multiple indian regional languages in same Jtextpane?

Comment: If you ask your answer with your own code then it is easy to get more accurate answer as you want

Comment: public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Hello!");
        j.setSize(200, 200);
        JTextPane k = new JTextPane();
        k.setFont(new Font("Shree-Guj-0768W", Font.PLAIN, 17));
       j.add(k);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }
}

i have set the gujrati font in jtextpane, the existing content appear in gujrati,but when i write in the jtextpane boxes appears. Can we have multiple indian regional languages in same Jtextpane?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First thing is to install the font.

Secondly set the font for `JTextPane` - 
for e.g if you want to set `Shivaji05` font for typing Marathi in `JTextPane` then use:

```
jTextPane1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Shivaji05", Font.PLAIN, 11));
```

Comment: Don't use 'magic numbers' like '0' for the font style.  Better to use `Font.PLAIN` (or another constant or an addition of them).

Comment: *"First thing is to install the font."*  +1  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font/8365030#8365030) to "How do you import a font?".

Comment: i have set the gujrati font in jtextpane, the existing content appear in gujrati,but when i write in the jtextpane boxes appears.
Can we have multiple indian regional languages in same Jtextpane?

Comment: Do you really need a `JTextPane` at all?  Is this styled (bold, italic, headers, paragraphs, embedded images..) text it is displaying?  Or can it be done purely with the font (and perhaps a bold/italic variant of that `Font`)?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the font for JTextPane.

Here is the link below how you can set the font and used it

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/39-how-change-jtextarea-font-font-size-color.html

http://javatechniques.com/blog/setting-jtextpane-font-and-color/

Comment: The font must have install in the system and if the font was found then it'll be support for write those languages.