# Set the font of texts retrieved from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, jtextfield

I have the user enter some words through a JTextField. I want to set the font of the string. Here is what I have so far.

```
Font f;
f = new Font(input.getText(), Font.ITALIC, 32);
word = new JLabel(f, SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Unfortunately, Java is throwing me a compiler error because JLabel doesn't accept Font as a parameter. Is it possible to set the font of a string retrieved from a text field and have it displayed on a JFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`JComponent.setFont(Font)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29).

> Sets the font for this component.

---

But better than a text field to set a font name, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149) for a (styled) combo or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365030/418556) that uses a list:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out :)