# How to use custom (installed) font for displaying non-english text in Java

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, awt

I am unable to use custom font for displaying Urdu text in my awt application. I am new to java and I have searched the api and internet thoroughly but to no avail. Interestingly, Urdu text can be displayed with fonts like Times New Roman, Arial etc but not with the font I want to use despite the fact that its ttf and is able to diplay all the glyphs.

What packages/classes I should use to remedy this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreceiated.

Comment: What have you tried? java.awt.Font.createFont is able to load TrueType or OpenType fonts from a file or an input stream. What happens when you load the font and then try to display Urdu text in it?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365030/418556) for importing and using a new font.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).