# add .ttf file to java project

Tags: java, fonts, awt, truetype

I have downloaded akshar.ttf file and want to add it to my java project. I have tried the following ways by searching online but nothing worked so far.

Try 1:

```
Font ttfBase = null;
        Font ttfReal = null;
        try {
            InputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("akshar.TTF"));
            ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
            ttfReal = ttfBase.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("akshar font not loaded.");
        }
```

Try 2:

```
Font font = new Font("akshar",Font.PLAIN,15);
```

I have the akshar.ttf file at the following places:-

1. java/jre/lib/fonts
2. bin folder of my project
3. src folder of my project

I am new to java and have tried all these by following various links online. Please help me where am i going wrong.

Comment: If it is in the `src` folder it should make its way into the `bin` folder automatically, shouldn't it?  The `Font` will need to be accessed by `URL` rather than `File`.  Check the [embedded-resource info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to gain the URL.

Comment: is it present in the same folder as your check class? The third try should work then; at least the `InputStream` object shouldn't be null.

Comment: As the font is part of the application (could be packed in a jar), do not use File but a resource: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/akshar.TTF")`. Mind that is *case-sensitive*!

Answer (score 7):

You can register the created font with the graphics environment , as below :

```
try {
   GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
     GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("akshar.TTF"));
} catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
 //Handle exception
}
```

Refer the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html).

Comment: Good point.  See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149) & [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365030/418556).

Comment: @Noob UnChained : I'm getting this error message `java.io.IOException: Can't read akshar.ttf
 at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Check the path and filename of the .ttf file , make sure it is correct !

Comment: @NoobUnChained  what is the correct place for placing the ttf file?

Answer (score -1):

Put your ttf into the assests folder :)