# Might not have been initialized error at null check

Tags: java, initialization, final

I'm checking if the variable is initialized but at that point netbeans is giving me `variable reader might not have been initialized` warning. How do I fix/suppress this?

This is my code (summary):

```
final Reader reader;
try {
        reader = new Reader(directory);
        //additional stuff that can cause an exception
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //do stuff
    } finally {
        if (reader != null);
    }
```

The point of the if check is to determine whether it is initialized.

And what is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `reader` was never initialized, it doesn't even have a null value.

change

```
final Reader reader;
```

to

```
Reader reader = null;
```

to make sure it has an initial value.

This way, if `reader = new Reader(directory);` throws an exception, `reader` will contain `null` when tested by the finally block.

Comment: When I do it I can not change the reader to something in the try statement

Comment: @WVrock I missed the fact that it's a final variable. Change it to non final.

Comment: But how should final keyword be used ?

Comment: coming from .net background, struggling with date vs calendar vs java.time, deprecations all around, and now this, just makes me think java really sucks

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign a finale Variable! You gotta change your

> final Reader reader;

to

```
Reader reader = null;
```

and give *reader* a initial value.