# Java GUI compatible with Mac and Windows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have a project whose GUI was implemented in MAC notebook, when I tried to run it in Windows, there is different GUI and also different buttons' characters. I checked the type of all used fonts, and I am sure they are all installed in windows, Are there any other things I have to consider to work in both platforms ?

Answer (score 2):

In swing there exists a [LookAndFeel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#example) which by default is set to be platform specific: adapt to the normal platform theme. A nice cross-platform look-and-feel is **nimbus**.

What the fonts are concerned: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font) where `registerFont` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can Swing as the same code you develop will run on Mac, Windows or Linux.

1. You can install Windows Builder for eclipse. Tute is here: 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeswfZz4IW0
   (till 5:05 in the video)
2. A comprehensive guide to Swing and its various components can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgkWfz7Vy40