# How to add multiple fonts to a string drawn by an Graphics2D object

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d

I have a `Graphics2D` object and I want to use its `drawString` method. I can call that method and pass a String and (x, y) positions, which is very nice. However, I also have the possibility to change the font of my `Graphics2D` object, using the `setFont` method, which expects a Font object. This is also very nice. Unfortunately this is not enough for me, because I intend to define multiple font texts to my Font object.

This is the textual representation I would like to transfer to my Font object:

```
font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
```

I have seen that I have the possibility to use the `AttributedCharacterIterator` interface to solve my problem, however, I am not sure how should I use that. I have seen that there is actually an implementation called `AttributedString`, which has a set of `Attributes`, but I am not sure how could I create an `AttributedString` object which could be used by the constructor of `Font` in such a way that my `Graphics2D` object will recognize the multiple fonts and apply them when I call `drawString`.

EDIT:

```
    public static AttributedString getFontByAttributes(String atts, String value)
    {
        String[] attributes = atts.split(",");
        AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(value);
        for (int attributeIndex = 0; attributeIndex < attributes.length; attributeIndex++)
        {
            attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, attributes[attributeIndex].trim());
        }
        return attributedString;
    }
//...
    public void drawTitle(Graphics2D g2d)
{
//...
        g2d.drawString(getFontByAttributes(Settings.titleFontString, Settings.title).getIterator(), Settings.headerWidthOffset, Settings.headerHeightOffset);
//...
}
```

In the code above I have tried with Andale Mono, which is known on the system where I test this application, however, in the generated graphics, the text is drawn in Times New Roman font. Something is wrong and unfortunately I don't have a clue about what could I be missing.

Comment: You are not using the AttributedString API correctly.  You want to apply your FONT attributes to specific substrings, using the `addAttribute(String, String, int, int)` method.  The method you're using sets the FONT for the whole string, overriding it entirely each time.

Comment: No, I intend to set the font for the whole string to be Lucida Grande. If Lucida Grande is not defined on the computer of the user, then the font of the string should be Lucida Sans Unicode and so on. But this solution overrides the font, so this doesn't solve my problem. I only thought this is a solution, because accidentally my tests didn't show the problems.

Comment: Yes, that is an entirely different problem then.  You should refer to this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270360/how-to-find-with-java-if-a-certain-font-is-installed-correctly-on-a-machine ) to resolve your problem.

Comment: I cannot use the solution to the referred question. My project generates an SVG on a server, which will be downloaded and viewed by the clients on their machine. So I don't have access to the client computer when the graphics are generated and, as a result java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames() will not help me.

Comment: "I intend to define multiple font texts to my Font object." Here I wanted to clarify the fact that I want to use alternative fonts in the same font object. I guess I was not clear enough, I am sorry for that. Is there any solution in Java to my problem, or should I make an ugly hack?

Comment: If your Java code is not going to run on the client machine, and the client machine is where the problem is, then no, there is no solution in Java.  You should probably repost the question more accurately.

Comment: I can solve the problem, I was just hoping there is a solution in Java. I don't see why "Unfortunately this is not enough for me, because I intend to define multiple font texts to my Font object." is not clear. I have a Font object and I want to assign multiple fonts to that. If the first is not defined on the client machine, then the second alternative should be used and so on. I believe you it is not clear, but I don't really understand which part is unclear. Also, I already have a solution, but that's not in Java and it is an ugly hack, I wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Graphics2D` has a `drawString(AttributedCharacterIterator, int, int)` method that you'll want to use.

Simply build up your `AttributedString` with all the different `TextAttribute.FONT` properties you want for each specific sub-range of the string, then call:

```
g2d.drawString(myAttributedString.getIterator(), x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and will tell you the result.

Comment: Both answers solve my problem, I have to chose tourqestomp's answer, because his answer was quicker, but I upvoted both.

Comment: @LajosArpad I agree, that's only fair

Comment: This somehow doesn't work in all cases. I have already created a Graphics2D object in a case and I have already set the font. In that case the usage of drawString described in both answers doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, `AttributedString` provides methods to allow you to apply rendering attributes to a `String`.  Seems obvious really.

After that, you can pass the `AttributedString`'s `AttributedCharacterIterator` to `Graphics2D` for rendering...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.LineMetrics;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestAttributedString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestAttributedString();
    }

    public TestAttributedString() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            AttributedString text = new AttributedString("Bunny rabits and flying ponies");
            text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24), 0, "Bunny rabits".length());
            text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.RED, 0, "Bunny rabits".length());

            text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD & Font.ITALIC, 32), 17, 17 + "flying ponies".length());
            text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 17, 17 + "flying ponies".length());

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            LineMetrics lm = fm.getLineMetrics(text.getIterator(), 0, text.getIterator().getEndIndex(), g);

            g2d.drawString(text.getIterator(), 0, (int)lm.getAscent() + lm.getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

You can check out [this](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7635) for more details

Comment: Thank you, I am experimenting right now, I will tell you my results.