# How do I check if font exists

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I'm working with java.awt.Font , How can I discover if the font defined is installed on the system?

Specifically, I have

```
Font font = new Font("FooBar", 0, 14);
```

I want to discover if "font" is a valid font on the system and default to something more universal if it isn't available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try checking your Font in a loop like this:

```
public class SO2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      GraphicsEnvironment g= null;
        g=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String []fonts=g.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(fonts[i]);
            if(fonts[i].equals("YOUR FONT")){
                System.out.println("Found!");
            }
    }

}}
```

It should output "Found!" if it locates your font.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

check it against:

```
fonts = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

and see what comes out and if it's in the list.

also see:

[How to find, with Java, if a certain font is installed correctly on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270360/how-to-find-with-java-if-a-certain-font-is-installed-correctly-on-a-machine)

and feel free to read up at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html

the trick with java is to always refer to the documentation.

it's hard at first to read, but once you get it down, it's indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()` or  `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()` to get `java.awt.Font objects`